# Computing Divisors with MAGMA

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, magma-cas

I am relatively new to MAGMA, and trying to use it to verify a computation. I would like to find the ramified points of the map $\phi : C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $[X:Y:Z] \mapsto [Y:Z]$, where $C$ is the curve defined by the affine equation $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-2)$. I am running into an error with the `RamificationDivisor` function:

```
> kbar := AlgebraicClosure(Rationals());
> P2<X,Y,Z> := ProjectiveSpace(kbar,2);
> P1<T,U> := ProjectiveSpace(kbar,1);
> C := Curve(P2, Y^2*Z - X*(X-Z)*(X-2*Z));
> C2 := Curve(P1);
> phi := map<C->C2|[Y,Z]>;
> D := RamificationDivisor(phi);

>> D := RamificationDivisor(phi);
                           ^
Runtime error in 'RamificationDivisor': Only implemented for maps between integral curves
```

I am relatively new to both MAGMA and arithmetic geometry, can someone explain the error, and whether there is a workaround?

Comment: You're getting this error because Magma can't compute function fields over an algebraically closed field. If you look in the package file `Magma/package/Geometry/Crv/pushpull.m` line 159, you'll see that this error is caused by the failure of `require HasFunctionField(Codomain(phi)) and HasFunctionField(Domain(phi))`. Instead, you should work over $\mathbb{Q}$. If you do this and run `Support(D)`, you'll see the places in the support of $D$, one of which is defined over an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way using Magma to know which extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ the place not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ lives in? When I run the same thing with the variable `kbar` replaced by `Rationals()`, I gen a place at (0 : 1 : 0) and a place at ($.1 : $.1 : 1). I'd like to see if Magma can tell me what that $.1 is...

Comment: Calling the place $v$, you can do `Parent(Eltseq(RepresentativePoint(v))[1]);`, which in this case returns `Number Field with defining polynomial $.1^2 + 1/3*(2*$.1 - 2) over its ground field`. This is still not terribly clear, so calling that $K$, then `AbsoluteField(K)` gives `Number Field with defining polynomial 27*$.1^4 - 4 over the Rational Field`. Calling this `L<z>`, then the point has coordinates `[1/2*(-3*z^2 + 2),z,1]`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your help!